# Unable to use &self to call a method of a struct inside another method of the struct

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

trying to use &self to call an async method of a struct within another async method. The compiler complains like so:

```
11 |     async fn mult(&mut self) {
   |                   ---------
   |                   |
   |                   `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |                   let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
12 |         self.a *= 2;
13 |         tokio::spawn(self.disp());
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      `self` escapes the associated function body here
   |                      argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

While I understand that the compiler cannot guarantee that &self would outlive the execution of display, how do I even tackle this ? Calling the method as an associated function comes to mind, but that is most likely practical only in toy code snippets like this.

Code :

```
struct A {
    a: i32,
}

impl A {
    async fn disp(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.a);
    }

    async fn mult(&mut self) {
        self.a *= 2;
        tokio::spawn(self.disp());
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let c = A{a: 2};

    c.mult();
}
```

Comment: aside: `use toskio;` does nothing.

Comment: What is `tokio::spawn` meant to do here? Why not just use `self.disp().await`?

Comment: @cafce25 Noted. Removed. Thanks.

Comment: @PitaJ merely trying to mimic the workflow in an actual codebase where I am facing the problem.

Comment: If you spawn this in a new task, you either have to create a `Copy` or have shared ownership via `Arc`. There is no way to achieve what you are trying to do with a normal `&self` function, a reference simply isn't enough to keep the object alive.

Comment: @Finomnis might have to think about restructuring the codedbase then. Thanks

Comment: @PitaJ Why is it odd to spawn in an async context? It's an intended usecase; `.await` does not necessarily allow the future to move to a different thread.